# Angular2 in Edge on https: HTTPS security is compromised by null

Tags: angular, https, microsoft-edge, angular2-seed

I've tried with `href="javascript:;"` instead of `href=""`

And I've only 'https' calls in Fidler.

I'm using angular2-seed for deployment.

In console, when I click on app.js it points to the place where 'Environment config'  is being shown. Maybe someone had same issue before?

```
var c=function(){function t(t,e,n){this.idle=t,this.keepalive=e,this.lastPing=null,this.viewContainerRef=n,t.setIdle(15),t.setTimeout(585),t.setInterrupts(s.DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES),e.interval(10),console.log("Environment config",u.Config)}
```

Comment: Please provide a code snippet to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Can you provide a Plunker that allows to reproduce?